# "ExistentialQuantification" and Eq instance

Tags: haskell

When I tried to use `ExistentialQuantification` I faced with a problem

Let's suppose you have a type

```
data T s = forall s. (Show s,Eq s) => T (String,s)
```

I want to write an instance `Eq` for this type, say:

```
instance Eq (T a) where
    (T (name,value)) == (T (name',value'))  | (name /= name') = False
                                            | otherwise = value == value'
```

but it fails:

```
Could not deduce (s1 ~ s)
from the context (Show s, Eq s)
```

Another instance declaration

```
instance Eq a => Eq (T a) where
```

results the same error:

```
   Could not deduce (s1 ~ s)
    from the context (Eq a)
```

Comment: First, why do you write `data T s`, don't you mean `data T`?  The `s` is purely phantom as it's not the same `s` as used in the constructor.  Second, you can't derive `Eq`, since there's no guarantee that `value` and `value'` will have the same type, so how do you compare them then?  You can do it by adding `Typeable` to the constraints and use `cast` to do a type conversion, but you have to write the `Eq` instance yourself.

Comment: Yes, data T s it's my mistake, I'll try to use typecasting

Comment: Are you sure you need this `forall`? Maybe `data T s = (Show s, Eq s) => T (String, s)` is what you are looking for?

Comment: @user3237465  I have to use heterogeneous lists  in my project.

Comment: @SergeySosnin Are you sure you have to use heterogeneous lists?  I won't argue if you have already determined that it's the best way, but quite often I see heterogeneous lists being used where they just make things more complicated.

Comment: @Sergey Sosnin, then you can use actual heterogeneous lists like this: http://ideone.com/6PPDLu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on my comment, here's how you can do it

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
module E where
import Data.Typeable

data T = forall s. (Show s, Eq s, Typeable s) => T String s

instance Eq T where
    T name value == T name' value' = name == name' && maybe False (== value') (cast value)
```

This assumes that if the types in the existential are different then the values should not compare equal.

Answer (score 2):

Each time you "open" an existential data type you expose a piece of data whose type has been forgotten. To handle this, Haskell must establish a type for this data from nothing and therefore it produces a completely unique, fresh type variable.

This means that if you open two different existentials then the fresh types will not coincide no matter what you do. This is the meaning of the error messages you received.

This is also, of course, the correct behavior. For instance, all we need to use your `T` constructor are instances of `Show` and `Eq`. Both `Int` and `String` satisfy this so the following are both valid values

```
data T = forall s. (Show s,Eq s) => T (String,s)

x, y :: T
x = T ("string", "string")
y = T ("int", 3)
```

but we cannot expect that the `Eq` instance for either `String` or `Int` is sufficient to compare `3 == "string"` as your instance `Eq T` attempts to do.

So how can this be resolved? We need an notion of equality which works regardless of the type of the data being stored inside of `T`. To do so we can establish a projection, e.g.

```
data T = forall s . T String s (s -> (String, Int))
```

where the third parameter to `T` is a function which produces both the values `show`n representation and an integer hash value which we'll use for equality

```
instance Eq T where
  T nm1 s1 f1 = T nm2 s2 f2 = 
    nm1 == nm2 && snd (f1 s1) == snd (f2 s2)
```

Now this works but the representation raises an issue—if the *only* thing we can do with our anonymously-typed value is apply it to its copatriot anonymously-typed function... then why not just do that in the first place?

```
data T = T String String Int

t :: Show s => String -> s -> (s -> Int) -> T
t nm s f = T nm (show s) (f s)
```